# Calculated Field in Row Values - Pandas Pivot - Conversion Rate

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot-table

I'm really new to Python and Pandas so bear with me please. I want to create a Pivot Table with a Calculated Field for the Conversion Rate ('Conversions' / 'Clicks') and show it accurately in the pivot's rows. Just like you would do in Excel

I've tried groupby and other options adding another column with the calculation but the end value is incorrect in the Pivot Table.

Heres an example:

```
data_to_pivot = {'Day': ['7/16/20','7/16/20','7/17/20','7/18/20'],
        'Country': ['Australia','Spain','Spain','Chile'],
        'Conversions': [2,24,54,50],
        'Clicks': [1201,2330,5453,1230]
        }

to_pivot = pd.DataFrame(data_to_pivot,columns=['Clicks','Conversions','Day','Country'])

to_pivot.pivot_table(index=['Country'],columns=['Day'],values=('Clicks','Conversions'),aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value='-').stack(0)

#Which gives:

_________


             Day         7/16/20    7/17/20    7/18/20     7/19/20     All
Country
                    
Australia    Clicks         1201       5453       1230        2330     10214
             Conversions       2         54         50          24       130

I thought that would work but if I pivot the results are wrong, for example:  
  
Clicks  Conversions   Day       Country. 
1201    2   1         7/16/02   Australia
5453    54  2         7/17/02   Australia
1230    50  3         7/18/02   Australia
2330    24  4         7/19/02  Australia
10214   120 4         7/19/02  Australia
  
Day.     7/16/02    7/17/20     7/18/20     7/19/20   Total. 
Clicks   1201       5453        1230        12544     20428. 
Conv.    2          54          50          144       250. 
Rate.    0.17%      0.99%       4.07%       2.20%    7.43%. 
  
The last day is wrong because its adds the sum? Should be 1.22%. @G.Anderson
_________
```

I would like to see the calculated field below the Clicks and Conversions values.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please show your attempts to add the column before the pivot, and how the result was wrong. It seems like the solution should be like `to_pivot['rate']=to_pivot['Conversions']/to_pivot['Clicks']` then pivot as you have already done

Comment: @G.Anderson y updated the question with the results and how what i see is wrong because it sums the values of the new cvr column and the rate is calculated wrong